# How can I pass a dynamic value to matIcon?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Just trying to pass a string into component input so I can have a dynamic icon. Is this possible? [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtes4d?file=app%2Falert.component.ts)

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-alert',
  template: `
    <mat-icon class="alert--{{context}}" *ngIf="icon">{{icon}}</mat-icon>
  `,
})
export class AlertComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() context: string;

  @Input() icon: string;

  @Input() message: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

```html
<mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
<app-alert [context]="'primary'" [icon]="'check'" [message]="'blah message working'"></app-alert>
```

Comment: It is possible, all you have to do is  `<mat-icon>{{icon}}</mat-icon>`

Comment: Issue comes from your `class="alert--{{context}}"`, it works without it

Comment: interesting thanks @Ploppy, you should add it as the answer.

Comment: @alphapilgrim improved answer with proper explanation and complete workaround.

Comment: nb: I recommend you to avoid data binding with `{{}}` inside html attributes.

Comment: you can bind a dynamic class by adding an object to your component then bind to `[ngClass]` something like `this.myClass['alert--' + context] = true` 
then in the template `[ngClass]='myClass'`

Comment: @k0hamed yes and there is even one more way to add a css class! Check the final version of my answer :)

Comment: @Ploppy yeah, it's the best as you mentioned except it doesn't support dynamic class name (which is the case here)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is mostly right.

Though the way you databind the CSS class breaks the material icon font because it removes the original classes required to transform the text into an svg icon.

Change this:

```html
<mat-icon class="alert--{{context}}" *ngIf="icon">{{icon}}</mat-icon>
```

To this:

```html
<mat-icon [className]="'mat-icon material-icons alert--'+context" *ngIf="icon">{{icon}}</mat-icon>
```

Or prefered:

```html
<mat-icon [ngClass]="'alert--'+context" *ngIf="icon">{{icon}}</mat-icon>
```

`ngClass` only appends the given string to the class attributes while `className` overrides it.

---

For learning purpose:
There is actually one more way to bind a static CSS class, which is, in my opinion, the best.

```
[class.myClass]="expression"
```

ex :

```
[class.myClass]="true"
```

would produce:

```
class="myClass"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get mat icons on condition

HTML:

```
<mat-icon>{{getIcon(event.type)}}</mat-icon>
```

TS:

```
getIcon(type){
    if(type = "assignment"){
      return "assignment"
    }
    else{
      return "xyz"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing Parth, but I would advise keeping functions out of templates as much as possible. Functions in templates is much less performant than a pipe/directive.